# JHipster executable WAR using dev profile instead of prod

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I package a WAR using `mvnw -Pprod package`. According to JHipster website:

> Please note that this WAR file uses the profile we selected when building it. As it was built using the prod file in the previous section, it will therefore run with the prod profile.

And also:

> When you run your production application from a WAR file, the default is to use the same profile(s) as used during packaging. If you want to override this, you can explicitly provide an alternative in VM argument

However, when I run my WAR without `--spring.profiles.active=prod`, it runs under the `dev` profile. 
What gives?

Comment: Right, my bad. `Welcome to the JHipster Generator v3.0.0`

Comment: This is rather old and there have been some issues with profile fixed since, try updating. Also the doc you are referring to is for latest version and this paragraph has been updated 11 days ago, so it probably does not apply to your version.

Comment: The doc for your version is at https://jhipster.github.io/documentation-archive/v3.0.0/

Comment: Cool stuff! If you'd like, post an answer and I will mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JHipster web site](https://jhipster.github.io/) documents the most recent version. In your case, your version is well behind latest so it does not longer match but you can find the archived documentation for your exact version at https://jhipster.github.io/documentation-archive/